# C++ VCL Interrogating .xlsb Excel database

Tags: c++, database, c++builder, vcl, xlsb

I need some help for interrogating an xlsb database (file) from a VCL C++ program; (using C++Builder XE2) mainly, i would like to query the data inside for simple viewing (its on the same machine, no networking involved), and i don't need to modify it ! so i would like to know :

1. Which control to use for connecting to an xlsb database
   (TDatabase, dbExpress ?)
2. How to use that control for the purpose
   of reading the data, (same as SQL?)
3. The difference between the regular xsl and xslb, and are they used in the same manner ?

I did some research before asking, but the information about that is pretty scarce !
(i'm on Win 7 64bit)

Thank you all !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never tested it with these files but i believe you can use a TADOConnection and then user Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers as the data provider, i know it can use access and excel files as a source, personally i have only ever used it for access files, but it might do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, i guess this will work, but what am i supposed to fill in for a Username and a Password ? its only a local file, and how do i query data ?

Comment: Do you have a sample file I can look at?

Comment: Sure, i'm working with a database of french words for use on an assignment, this database (.xlsb) can be found here (direct link) http://www.lexique.org/public/Lexique380.Excel.zip

Comment: Thanks. i've had no luck in the above approach for that file, would it cause you issues if the file was imported into another file. i know the above approach does work for access file so it may be an idea to import the file into that first and work from there?